# KnockoutJS IF binding - keep DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, data-binding

The `if` binding removes DOM and stops executing inner `data-bind` attributes if the condition is `false`.

Is it possible to keep the DOM even when condition is `false`? I just want to stop executing `data-bind` when condition is `false` but I do not wish to remove any DOM due to JQuery bindings etc.

Comment: Why can't you use `visible` then? Does your `data-bind` use binding-handlers that perform operations themselves, regardless of `click` or other events (they shouldn't)?

Comment: The visible binding does not stop execution of `data-bind` attributes that are inside of the element. I have all website pages inserted in the DOM from the beginning. I apply binding to all of them. Some of the pages contain data that I do not have in the beginning. The observables are empty. In such a case the `data-bind` should not be executed. First when I fill in observable from database, the inner `data-bind` binding should be executed.

Comment: If you are using KO you should not rely on the state stored in DOM. So you should move all your jquery bindings to custom KO bindings, in this case when the `if` is evaluated to true again your jquery bindings will be automatically reapplied when the `data-bind` are evaluated.

Comment: This was an example. I have also other libraries such as Framework7 and others. I cannot control bindings of all of them...

Answer (score 1):

I came with the following solution which basically delays knockout binding application until a condition is satisfied.

It does not remove binding when the condition becomes `false` but this is not necessary in my case.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['applyWhen'] = {
  init: function() {
    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, model, bindingContext) {
    if (!element.bindingApplied && Boolean(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()))) {
      element.bindingApplied = true;
      ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);
    }
  }
};
```